# How to calculate this integral about exp?

Tags: integration

> If $X\sim N(0,σ^2)$, then the expected value of $\exp(X)$ is $\exp(σ^2/2)$.

How to show this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\mathbb E[\exp(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{x}\; dx$$
where $f(x)$ is the density of $X$.  Combine $e^x$ with the exponential in $f(x)$, complete the square, ...

Comment: after plug in the probability density of the normal distribution, how to compute this integral?

Comment: As I said, complete the square.